# Inapp Webview Flutter Hide an element by class name

Tags: flutter

I want to hide an element by class name. But it's not working

```
 onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                        webViewController?.evaluateJavascript(source: '''
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClassName');
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
              elements[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
          ''');
```

I use InappWebView package and try to hide element by class name